# Row is [object Object] when fetching a database row in SQLite3

Tags: node.js, database, sqlite

It seems that SQLite 3 deals with database reading requests async. When I request the row with the code below, I either get `[object Object]` as `row.task_name`. Does anyone know what causes it and what would resolve it?

```
 function showTask(num) {
      //check if task's number exists, return error if it does not


      // if task's number exists, show task name
    var sql = "SELECT num FROM Tasks ";
    sql += "WHERE num = ?";

    DB.get(sql, num, function(err, row) {
        console.log("fetching");
        if (err) {
            console.log("An error occured when fetching from the database: " + err);
            return;
        } else {
            callback(row);
        };
    });
};

function callback(row) {
    console.log("The Task is named: " + row);
}

showTask(6);
```

I implemented the callback because it was recommended to me by another stackoverflow question's top answer. The result is exactly the same, whether I instantly log it or use the callback of row:

```
node index.js
Connected to the database.
Foreign Key Enforcement enabled.
DB Schema loaded.
Added the task succesfully.
fetching
The Task is named: [object Object]
Disconnected from the database.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Version 01**

```
function showTask(callback, num) {
    if (num == null || num == undefined) {
        callback("num is not defined");
        return;
    }

    var sql = "SELECT task_name FROM Tasks WHERE num = ?";

    console.log("fetching");
    DB.get(sql, num, callback);
};


function callback(err, row) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("An error occured when fetching from the database: " + err);
        return;
    }

    console.log("Row: " + JSON.stringify(row));
    console.log("The Task is named: " + row.task_name);
}

showTask(callback, 6);
```

**Version 2**

```
function showTaskWithCallBack(callBack) {
    if (typeof callBack === 'function') {
        return function(num) {
            if (num == null || num == undefined) {
                callBack("num is not defined");
                return;
            }

            var sql = "SELECT task_name FROM Tasks WHERE num = ?";

            console.log("fetching");
            DB.get(sql, num, callBack);
        }
    } else {
        console.error("callBack undefined");
    }
};


function callBack(err, row) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("An error occured when fetching from the database: " + err);
        return;
    }

    console.log("Row: " + JSON.stringify(row));
    console.log("The Task is named: " + row.task_name);
}

var taskShower = showTaskWithCallBack(callBack);

taskShower(6);
```

Comment: That solves the object issue, thank you. However, if I specify it to row.task_name it now returns that the task name is undefined. Is that just how SQLite3 works or have I made a second mistake somewhere?

Comment: can you show me the result of the console log?

Comment: you are selecting `num` column from the `Tasks` table. Why would it return  `task_name`  column? @CaseyKuilman

Comment: Oh my lord. I have been staring at this for an hour now, thank you for making me realize that. I'll mark your answer as correct.